# How to create a new table Donor such that it belongs to another table Campaign and  that their relationship is satisfied?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am new to rails and have just been trying to build a campaign donation page. I  have a single Donor object I am trying to relate to a Campaign. I have added the following to the Donor model(donor.rb):

```
class Donor < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign
end
```

and I have added the following in my Campaign model(campaign.rb) :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :donors,:dependent => :destroy
end
```

Now how do I go about creating a new Donor object such that it reflect this relationship.
I thought by replacing in donors_controller.rb

```
def new
@donor = Donor.new
```

by

```
def new
@campaign=current_campaign
@donor = @campaign.donors.build
```

will do the job. But I get an error

```
undefined method `donors' for nil:NilClass
```

Ideally what I would like to do is just display the donors of a particular campaign on its 'show' page and I wanted to link the id of campaign as the id of donor as soon as it is created.I just cant understand how to go about it.
Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that `@campaign` is not set in your donors_controller. How are you trying to set it?

Comment: well i edited it now, i have added @campaign = current_campaign .It doesnt work even now though :(

Comment: What does current_campaign look like?